# How to fix door angle?

Tags: doors

What can I do to fix a door that is off-center? the top left is touching the frame. There's a wider gap on the top right than bottom right. We drilled it into frame so it got a little closer but it's still off. We couldn't figure out why it's off.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The first step is to use a level to see what is out of whack.

Comment: Is the door plumb?  Is the jamb plumb?

Answer (score 1):

The doors (and windows) has to be plumb, level, and square. The door has to be parallel to the ground, vertical, and also not skewed (corners at 90 degrees / right angles).

Rough opening is called rough because it doesn't have to be perfectly plumb, level, and square.

To bring doors to be level and square you use shims and level. Also check for square by measuring corner-to-corner distances (e.g. top-left corner to bottom-right corner distance has to equal to top-right corner to bottom-left corner distances).

[image]